# Packaging android code into jar file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to package the android code into a jar file so that I can use it in another project. But when I do that I get the following error messages. I am not sure how to do this correctly if someone has done it please post a link and some details would be really helpful.

Thanks

```
Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml
Origin 1: C:\Users\Admin\workspace\Test\bin\resources.ap_
Origin 2: C:\Users\Admin\workspace\Test\lib\JarLib.jar
```

I have to use it in lots of project so I want to compile it as jar just like other libraries available online such as twitter4j, googleAnalytic, androidsupportlibrary and I need to know which folder are compulsory to include in Jar file. I have tried building it by excluding the resources folder and using eclipse->export, though it builds the jar but upon including it in another test project displays the above errors messages.

Comment: When you export project as a jar file just remove AndroidManifest, bin, lib,gen and resources from it then export it, only src directory is enough if you are not using resources from it.

Comment: The error comes because, Your jar file contains manifest file. And your project too, So its found as duplicate.

Comment: But I am using resources , still when I build it I try to exclude the manifest file but when it gets to generate page it asks for whether you want to create the manifest automatically or use existing from workspace, so I have to select either option. I cant get rid of it.

Comment: If you are using resources in project then your are not able to used your project as a jar in other project. For this you have to make android library project and use it in other project.

Comment: Also option is Generate the manifestfile.

Comment: Thanks then I think the only way that works for me is to use it as library project though I really don't like doing that way. What do you mean by generate the manifest file will it solve the issue I am having and how please elaborate.

Comment: Its only for jar packed with source files not resources..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11369/discussion-between-user606669-and-user370305)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that error occurs when your content doesn't contain a purely java files!!

If your "own classes" are purely Java, create a JAR file, and add that JAR file to whichever Android projects you want it in (put it in libs/ of the project, and also add it to your build path if you are using Eclipse). If you will be needing Android resources and such, though, you can create an Android library project, either for [Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) or [outside of Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html).

Or Project Properties -> Select Android Tab ->check isLibrary Option->Ok

Answer (score 2):

Better to build as a Library Project. Right click the Project( which is having common code)  -> Select **Properties** -> Select **Android Tab** ->check **isLibrary** Option->**Ok** as shown below :[image]. You can add this as referenced project to another Project by clicking **Add** button in the above image. Then the Library Projects directory is created having jar file as shown below :

[image]